# Golang serving static files, please explain what happens in these 3 lines of code

Tags: go

I'm learning go web programming and understand everthing but I'm getting lost in this 3 apparently simple lines:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
handler := http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs)
mux.Handle("/static/", handler)
```

...I have read the go src for the following lines and this is what I can infer:

1. `http.Dir("public")` is casting string "public" to type Dir.
2. then we serve a file (including all its content) with http.FileServer()
3. We strip prefix because now we are inside a handleFunc() for fs
4. StripPrefix() created a HandlerFunc()
5. mux.Handle() registers HandlerFunc() in the mux.
6. Deep goes the rabbit hole... and then this goroutine `go c.serve(ctx)` by `func (srv *Server) Serve(l net.Listener) error {}`
7. So each static file inside `/public/` dir is served concurrently by our server.

Can someone confirm or explain what exactly is happening in the 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at the docs I think this is what happens:

```
http.Dir("public")
```

you are converting the `string` `"public"` to the type [`Dir`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Dir) which implements the [`FileSystem`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileSystem) interface

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("public"))
```

which according to the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) does:

> FileServer returns a handler that serves HTTP requests with the
>   contents of the file system rooted at root.

`root` being the `Dir` you are passing as a parameter

```
handler := http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs)
```

you wrap the `Handler` `fs` in the `Handler` created by the [`StripPrefix`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) func

which according to the [docs](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) does:

> StripPrefix returns a handler that serves HTTP requests by removing
>   the given prefix from the request URL's Path and invoking the handler
>   h

`h` being the `Handler` `fs` you are passing as a parameter

```
mux.Handle("/static/", handler)
```

you let all requests starting with the path `/static/` be handled by `handler`

So in short all requests for the the path `/static/` will get stripped of the `/static/` prefix and will return a file from the `public` directory on you server with the same name, eg. a request to `/static/requestedFile.txt` will return the file under `public/requestedFile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Currently going through a GoLang tutorial by Soham Kamani, and found that his explanation helps a ton:

```
func newRouter() *mux.Router {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/hello", handler).Methods("GET")

    // Declare the static file directory and point it to the
    // directory we just made
    staticFileDirectory := http.Dir("./assets/")

    // Declare the handler, that routes requests to their respective filename.
    // The fileserver is wrapped in the `stripPrefix` method, because we want to
    // remove the "/assets/" prefix when looking for files.
    // For example, if we type "/assets/index.html" in our browser, the file server
    // will look for only "index.html" inside the directory declared above.
    // If we did not strip the prefix, the file server would look for
    // "./assets/assets/index.html", and yield an error
    staticFileHandler := http.StripPrefix("/assets/", http.FileServer(staticFileDirectory))

    // The "PathPrefix" method acts as a matcher, and matches all routes starting
    // with "/assets/", instead of the absolute route itself
    r.PathPrefix("/assets/").Handler(staticFileHandler).Methods("GET")
    return r
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confirming:

You are registering an automatic handler for static files. Requests in the form: `GET /static/some_file` will be handled concurrently by delivering files from the `/public` directory.